Delphi 11.3: save MHT with resources without dialog
My code:
uses
  System.SysUtils, MSHTML, ActiveX, SHDocVw;

implementation

procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  WebBrowser1.Navigate('google.com');
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  Dispatch: IDispatch;
  OleCommand: IOleCommandTarget;
  vaIn, vaOut: OleVariant;
  FilePath: WideString;
begin
  Dispatch := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2) as IDispatch;

  if Succeeded(Dispatch.QueryInterface(IOleCommandTarget, OleCommand)) then
  begin
    FilePath := ExtractFilePath(ParamStr(0)) + 'google.mht'; // Путь для сохранения MHT файла

    vaIn := FilePath;
    vaOut := OleVariant(True); // Передаем True для перезаписи файла, если он уже существует

    OleCommand.Exec(nil, OLECMDID_SAVEAS, OLECMDEXECOPT_PROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);
  end;
end;

When you click the button, a dialog box for saving the web page opens.
I need to save web page with resources in MHT without dialog boxes.

I tried this:




command OLECMDID_
option OLECMDEXECOPT_
dialog box hidden?
saves MHT?




_SAVEAS
_DONTPROMPTUSER
❌ appears
❌ only HTML


_SAVEAS
_PROMPTUSER
❌ appears
✅ yes


_SAVEAS
_DODEFAULT
❌ appears
✅ yes


_SAVE
_DONTPROMPTUSER
✅
❌ don't save at all


_SAVE
_PROMPTUSER
✅
❌ don't save at all


_SAVE
_DODEFAULT
✅
❌ don't save at all




I tried to use execWB like this:
WB := (WebBrowser1.DefaultInterface as IWebBrowser2);
WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SAVEAS, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);

Dialog box also appears and what's most important it saves only html/htm and txt, no MHT.

Default path in dialog box is always the path where the file was last saved, not FilePath's content.


What do I wrong? How to save a web page in FilePath as MHT format without showing a dialog box? Complete project on GitHub.

Why do you set vaOut := FilePath; and then on the very next line use vaOut := OleVariant(True);? What is the purpose of doing that? And why do you declare vaIn, but  never assign it a value before using it?

Assign your path to vaIn instead of vaOut. Also try using .execWB().

i tried vaIn := FilePath; dialog box also appears.
i tried execWB like this:
WB := (WebBrowser1.DefaultInterface as IWebBrowser2);
WB.ExecWB(OLECMDID_SAVEAS, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER, vaIn, vaOut);
Dialog box also appears and what's most important it saves only html/htm and txt. No MHT.
One more thing: default path in dialog box always path where the file was last saved

IDM_SAVEAS states: "The file path portion of pvaIn parameter is ignored".

The problem is still relevant.
